# How can I progress this derivation?

Tags: proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I'm learning propositional calculus in a discrete mathematics course.

I'm trying to kick the habit of using axioms like equations and now I'm a little stuck and could use a nudge.

Using a compact Hilbert system of axioms:
$$
\begin{array}[ll]
\text{a1}:&A\lor A\Rightarrow A\\
\text{a2}:&A\Rightarrow A\lor B\\
\text{a3}:&A\lor B\Rightarrow B\lor A\\
\text{a4}:&(A\Rightarrow B)\Rightarrow((C\Rightarrow A)\Rightarrow (C\Rightarrow B))\\
\end{array}
\\\\
\text{Prove: }A\Rightarrow A
$$

I derived the following:

$$
\begin{array}[lll]
\\
1&(A\Rightarrow B)\Rightarrow((A\lor A\Rightarrow A)\Rightarrow (A \lor A\Rightarrow B))&\text{using C=$A\lor A$ in a4}\\
2&(A\Rightarrow B)\Rightarrow (A\lor A\Rightarrow B)&\text{mp using 1 and a1}\\
3&(A\Rightarrow A\lor B)\Rightarrow(A\lor A \Rightarrow A\lor B)&\text{sub. A$\lor$ B for B}\\
4&A\lor A\Rightarrow A\lor B&\text{mp using 3 and a2}\\
\end{array}
$$
I'm pretty sure I'm not too far off of getting this to come together but I'm a little stumped as to an appropriate substitution.

Or have I taken a wrong turn in one of my substitutions already?

Comment: How does your second step follow from axiom 2?

Comment: I think I'm substituting again instead of deducing ...

Comment: The only way to derive $A \Rightarrow A$ is using axiom 4 (or axiom 1, if you could first derive $(A \Rightarrow A) \vee (A \Rightarrow A)$, which seems harder rather than easier).  Replacing $B$ and $C$ with $A$, and $A$ with $B$, in axiom 4 gives you $(B \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow ((A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (A \Rightarrow A))$.  So if you can get $B \Rightarrow A$ and $A \Rightarrow B$ for *any* formula $B$, you have the result.  Can you see what $B$ should be?

Comment: If I substituted $A\lor A$ for B I could use mp to eliminate the first implication leaving $(A\Rightarrow A\lor A)\Rightarrow (A\Rightarrow A)$ and then if I use a specialization of a2 I can use mp again to leave me with $A\Rightarrow A$? (I will explore this on my chalk board but I think that's the direction you're pointing me)

Comment: @mjqxxxx Thank you for your help, it's greatly aided my understanding.  I think I will try to find a book or site with a list of problems so I can practice this more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to derive $A \Rightarrow A$ is using axiom 4 (or axiom 1, if you could first derive $(A \Rightarrow A) \vee (A \Rightarrow A)$, which seems harder rather than easier).  Replacing $B$ and $C$ with $A$, and $A$ with $B$, in axiom 4 gives $(B\Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow ((A\Rightarrow B)\Rightarrow(A\Rightarrow A))$.  So if you can get $B \Rightarrow A$ and $A \Rightarrow B$ for *any* formula $B$, you have the result.  Using $A\vee A$ in place of $B$ works.  Here's a proof:
$$
\begin{array}{ l l l }
\text{a.} & (A \vee A\Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow ((A\Rightarrow A\vee A)\Rightarrow (A\Rightarrow A)) & \text{(specialization of axiom 4)} \\
\text{b.} & (A\Rightarrow A\vee A)\Rightarrow(A\Rightarrow A) & \text{(a. and axiom 1, using modus ponens)} \\
\text{c.} & A\Rightarrow A\vee A & \text{(specialization of axiom 2)} \\
\text{d.} & A\Rightarrow A & \text{(b. and c., using modus ponens)} \\
\end{array}
$$